# How to implement RandomUnderSampler in a scikit learn pipline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imblearn

I have a scikit learn pipeline to scale numeric features and encode categorical features. It was working fine until I tried to implement the [RandomUnderSampler](https://imbalanced-learn.org/en/stable/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.RandomUnderSampler.html) from imblearn. My goal is to implement the undersampler step since my dataset is very imbalanced 1:1000.

I made sure to use the Pipeline method from imblearn instead of sklearn. And below is the code I've tried.

Code data works (using sklearn pipeline) without the undersampler method.

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from imblearn.pipeline import make_pipeline as make_pipeline_imb
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline as Pipeline_imb

from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
class TypeSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, dtype):
        self.dtype = dtype
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        assert isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame)
        return X.select_dtypes(include=[self.dtype])

transformer = Pipeline([
    # Union numeric, categoricals and boolean
    ('features', FeatureUnion(n_jobs=1, transformer_list=[
         # Select bolean features                                                  
        ('boolean', Pipeline([
            ('selector', TypeSelector('bool')),
        ])),
         # Select and scale numericals
        ('numericals', Pipeline([
            ('selector', TypeSelector(np.number)),
            ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
        ])),
         # Select and encode categoricals
        ('categoricals', Pipeline([
            ('selector', TypeSelector('category')),
            ('encoder', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')),
        ])) 
    ])),
])
pipe = Pipeline([('prep', transformer), 
                 ('clf', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, class_weight='balanced'))
                 ])
```

Code that does not work (using imblearn pipeline) with the undersampler method.

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from imblearn.pipeline import make_pipeline as make_pipeline_imb
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline as Pipeline_imb

from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
class TypeSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, dtype):
        self.dtype = dtype
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        assert isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame)
        return X.select_dtypes(include=[self.dtype])

transformer = Pipeline_imb([
    # Union numeric, categoricals and boolean
    ('features', FeatureUnion(n_jobs=1, transformer_list=[
         # Select bolean features                                                  
        ('boolean', Pipeline_imb([
            ('selector', TypeSelector('bool')),
        ])),
         # Select and scale numericals
        ('numericals', Pipeline_imb([
            ('selector', TypeSelector(np.number)),
            ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
        ])),
         # Select and encode categoricals
        ('categoricals', Pipeline_imb([
            ('selector', TypeSelector('category')),
            ('encoder', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')),
        ])) 
    ])),  
])
pipe = Pipeline_imb([
                 ('sampler', RandomUnderSampler(0.1)),
                 ('prep', transformer), 
                 ('clf', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, class_weight='balanced'))
                 ])
```

Here is the error I get:

```py
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in __init__(self, steps, memory, verbose)
    133     def __init__(self, steps, memory=None, verbose=False):
    134         self.steps = steps
--> 135         self._validate_steps()
    136         self.memory = memory
    137         self.verbose = verbose

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/imblearn/pipeline.py in _validate_steps(self)
    144             if isinstance(t, pipeline.Pipeline):
    145                 raise TypeError(
--> 146                     "All intermediate steps of the chain should not be"
    147                     " Pipelines")
    148 

TypeError: All intermediate steps of the chain should not be Pipelines
```

Comment: I couldn't find any other way but to flatten the pipeline by taking steps out of the nested pipelines and stack them up to a single `imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you explore imblean's code in file `imblearn/pipeline.py` [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/blob/master/imblearn/pipeline.py), under function `_validate_steps`, they will check each item in `transformers` whether there is a transformer that is an instance of scikit's Pipeline or not (`isinstance(t, pipeline.Pipeline)`).

From your code, `transformers` are

1. `RandomUnderSampler`
2. `transformer`

and class `Pipeline_imb` inherits scikit's Pipeline while using `Pipeline_imb` in your code is redundant.

That has been said, I would adjust your code like below

```
transformer = FeatureUnion(n_jobs=1, transformer_list=[
     # Select bolean features                                                  
    ('selector1', TypeSelector('bool'),
     # Select and scale numericals
    ('selector2', TypeSelector(np.number)),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
     # Select and encode categoricals
    ('selector3', TypeSelector('category')),
    ('encoder', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
])

pipe = Pipeline_imb([
    ('sampler', RandomUnderSampler(0.1)),
    ('prep', transformer), 
    ('clf', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, class_weight='balanced'))
])
```